# diff to html (diff2html) program

Tags: html, diff

I'm looking for a "diff to html" program, which would generate a static html page from a given diff/patch file.

I've googled for it of course, but apart from some scripts I've found there's no "real project" (e.g. no package in Debian/Ubuntu).

Have I missed something? Can you recommend anything?

Comment: https://diff2html.xyz/ looks like it would answer your question (for anyone else looking)

Answer (score 28):

You can use [diff2html.py](http://wiki.droids-corp.org/articles/d/i/f/Diff2html.html) that is able to create a side-by-side diff in a static html page, from an unified diff input. The script is written in python.

```
cat foo.diff | python diff2html.py > foo.html
```

Comment: diff2html.py does not produce clean xhtml and you have a tough time, if you need to process is as xml.

Answer (score 25):

[pygments](http://pygments.org/) has syntax highlighting for diff (and for lots of other languages), and can be used as a library or a command-line program. Is that the sort of thing you're looking for? If not please clarify the question...

Comment: Pygments is cool, it's too bad they don't support side by side diff rendering.

Comment: This was useful for me:

    `diff -U9999999 -y file_before.php file_after.php | pygmentize -l diff -f html -O full -o file_diff.html`

Comment: @jwhitlock excellent! Thanks a lot. I had to select `-u` instead of `-y` (side by side) though, otherwise diff was complaining of "conflicting output style options".

Answer (score 19):

Something along the lines of:

```
vim test.diff -c TOhtml -c ":saveas test.html" -c ":q" -c ":q"
```

works well, and you can change the color-scheme of the diff by changing the color scheme in vi.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning TOhtml! Works wonders!

Comment: And it works for vimdiff too!

Comment: For those who want to use the vimdiff output, try the following: 

    vimdiff $PREV $NEW -c TOhtml -c ":saveas $OUT" -c ':q!' -c ':q!' -c ':q!'

Comment: I exported to html, as suggested, but output (.html) does not prettify? Any suggestion @daniel-zinn how making this work?

Answer (score 10):

http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/diff2html

Comment: Tool reads diff output from standard in. But: it requires both files on command line as well:  "Pipe stdout of diff to stdin of /home/fapgg/diff2html (slightly faster): diff file1 file2 | /home/fapgg/diff2html [options] file1 file2", i.e. it will not work on existing diff/patch file

Comment: As NPM module [diff2html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff2html)

Comment: [diff2html](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html) is hosted now on github.

Answer (score 8):

how about [Text-Diff-HTML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Diff-HTML/), [difflib.HtmlDiff](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.HtmlDiff), [CSDiff](http://www.componentsoftware.com/Products/CSDiff/)?

Comment: These 3 tools appear to generate diff files. I think the original question was asking for prettifying already generated diffs.

Comment: For an online version, check out http://changedetection.com/ and http://imnosy.com/

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried http://prettydiff.com/ as it ignores differences in white space and comments.

[Disclaimer: this is my site]

Answer (score 5):

There's also [2html](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#2html.vim) in Vim, which works very well, and it's built-in: it takes a file that Vim knows how to highlight its syntax, and creates an HTML with the correct formatting.
To use it, just open the wanted file with Vim, and source the 2html script. It will open the converted file in a new buffer, which can be saved. Here:

```
vim example.diff
```

and then in Vim,

```
:so /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/2html.vim
:wqa
```

Answer (score 5):

The best I've found that produces nice side-by-side diffs is this script:

http://tools.ietf.org/tools/rfcdiff/

Although it's designed to be used on RFCs it works with any text file.

This project also has nice output, but I'm not sure if it can be used without subversion:
http://code.google.com/p/coderev/

Answer (score 3):

I use [htmlize](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize) in Emacs.  Doesn't come with Emacs, and assumes you're using Emacs.  Relies on the syntax highlighting of Emacs's Diff mode.  Only good for doing one file at a time.  *Does the right thing* for me.

Comment: Once you installed it with M-x package-install htmlize (within emacs), you can simply call emacs as `emacs --file fms-src-77-to-78.diff -f htmlize-file -f kill-emacs` (though this still requires you to hit enter once)

Answer (score 3):

I found [coderev](http://code.google.com/p/coderev/), demo looks nice